# odoo V8 coding error when load file, store it in a binary field and then try to parse it

Tags: utf-8, base64, odoo, binaryfiles, odoo-8

I have the transient object:

```py
class new_import(models.TransientModel):
     _name = 'new.import'
     data_file = fields.Binary('File')
```

I call a wizard to load the file in the binary field and then i want to parse it.

In the function to parse the file i do:

```py
data_file = base64.b64decode(self.data_file)
lines = data_file.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    result = line[6:11]
```

but when i read the lines if there is a special character the length of the line isn't the same in all lines,

the file is utf8 in the origin

this must be an error when save the file in binary and then decode back to string

If i read the file directly with python with out store it in a binary field i can read it correctly:

```py
codecs.open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
result = line[6:11].encode('utf-8')
```

How can i avoid storing the file in base64 or how can i after decode correctly to string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No way to do it with the binary field. When the file is stored in base64 some information is missing and then is imposible to recover it doing base64.b64decode. I will try to parse the field with out binary field. The problem is how the user select the file in a form. ¿any idea?